# ContentProvider и openFile: отдача файлов в зависимости от URI

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть наследованный LocalFileContentProvider в нем openFile. Контент провайдер используется для работы с WebView, чтобы на загружаемой страничке подкидывать скрипты, стили, данные, картинки... И это выглядело в HTML странице следующим образом:

```
content://com.example/images/picture.jpg
content://com.example/scripts/main.js
content://com.example/styles/main.css
```

Надо, чтобы URI "раскладывала": /images, /scripts, /styles... все Файлы будут храниться в Assets/Provider_html. Или если можно сделать в под папках: /images, /scripts, /styles... А в Java коде, чтобы загрузка страницы в WebView выглядело так:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("content://com.example/TList2.htm?Status=Good");
```

т.е. чтобы URI расскладывался следующим образом: загружалась страница TList2.htm в WebView, затем URI смотрел Status= , если допустим равен Good, то это соответствовало Data2.txt, если равен NoGood, то это соответствовало Data4.txt. И передавалось в HTML страницу, допустим Data2.txt, для того что бы там в JavaScript: var sd = читало файл Data2.txt. Или передавать в HTML страницу URI и там читать: var sd = читало content://com.example/TList2.htm?Status=Good или так content://com.example/?Status=Good

Сейчас работает таким образом: файлы подгружаются так

```
content://com.example/picture.jpg
content://com.example/main.js
content://com.example/main.css
```

Страница загружается в WebView

```
mWebView.loadUrl("content://com.example/TList2.htm");
```

Данные пока не передаются...

Как реализовать эти вещи в openFile, чтобы он в зависимости от URI отдавал нужные файлы + загружал данные... Вот, что есть сейчас:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.LocalFileContentProvider";

private static final String IMAGES_FOLDER_STR = "images/*";
private static final String SCRIPTS_FOLDER_STR = "scripts/*";
private static final String STYLES_FOLDER_STR = "styles/*";
private static final String T_LIST_STR = "*?Status=*";
private static final String T_STR = "*?id=#";

private static final int IMAGES_FOLDER_ID = 15;
private static final int SCRIPTS_FOLDER_ID = 16;
private static final int STYLES_FOLDER_ID = 17;
private static final int T_LIST_ID = 18;
private static final int T_ID = 19;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;
static
{
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, IMAGES_FOLDER_STR, IMAGES_FOLDER_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SCRIPTS_FOLDER_STR, SCRIPTS_FOLDER_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, STYLES_FOLDER_STR, STYLES_FOLDER_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, T_LIST_STR, T_LIST_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, T_STR, T_ID);

}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
{

    Log.d("LocalFileContentProvider","fetching: " + uri);

    String path = getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + uri.getPath();
    File file = new File(path);
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = null;
    try
    {
        parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.d("LocalFileContentProvider", "uri " + uri.toString(), e);
    }
    return parcel;
}
```

Как я понимаю, нужно вставить штуку такого плана в  public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile; как правильно это сделать?

```
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case IMAGES_FOLDER_ID:
            //открытие папки с картинками если указано в URI images/
            break;
        case SCRIPTS_FOLDER_ID:
            //открытие папки со скриптами если указано в URI scripts/
            break;
        case STYLES_FOLDER_ID:
            //.....
            break;
        case TRIP_LIST_ID:
            //открытие нужного файла...
            break;
        case TRIP_ID:
            //открытие нужного файла...
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
```

В основном Java коде дописан еще такой кусок:

```
try
{
    for (String fileName : getAssets().list("Provider_html"))
    {
        File outputFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        InputStream in = getAssets().open( "Provider_html/" +fileName);

        copy(in,out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d(LOG, "error with copying files", e);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, ХэшКод!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно зачем такие сложности с ContentProvider, если можно загружать страницы из /assets таким вот образом:

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Provider_html/TList2.htm");

А всё остальное делать средствами HTML/JS...

Возможно я не понял цели автора, т.к. описано достаточно сумбурно.

Comment: Насчет прямой загрузки из Assets я в курсе. Просто в дальнейшем Контент провайдер все эти вещи будет брать из БД, а Assets это пока промежуточная вещь, что бы все настроить...